# pg module and nodejs - "LIKE" operand on query

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-like

I'm using nodejs 0.10.12 and the node-postgre (pg module) 2.2.0

I have a query like the following where I use the `LIKE` operator

`var query = client.query('SELECT t_name FROM type  WHERE t_name LIKE $1 ',[typetolook])`

If I write `Mu` in the search form I see in the console zero results even if my data base contains the word `Museum`.

Am I missing something? Is there a bug with `LIKE` operator?

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a `%` in your query.

```
client.query("SELECT t_name FROM type WHERE t_name LIKE $1", [typetolook + '%']);
```

Comment: this is what I thought too , and I edited the code just like you said, but now I get a syntax error...

Comment: Thanks... But now I get `bind message supplies 1 parameters , but prepared statement "" requires 0` Honestly, I have no idea what this is

Comment: @slevin Found an example [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/test/integration/client/prepared-statement-tests.js#L30). The trick is to append `%` to the query parameter.

Comment: Oh, yes, add the `%` next to `typetolook`. Thanks. It worked fine.